# RoboElectric ShadowIntent.getIntentClass is not equal to the actual java activity

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I am testing my android app code using roboelectric. As part of that I wanted to assert the next activity opened on the app.

Previously I used the following code:

```
Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, EODCountActivity.class);
Intent actual = shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application).getNextStartedActivity();
assertEquals(expectedIntent.getComponent(), actual.getComponent());
```

and it worked perfectly fine. but when I switched to the following version, the assertion fails.

```
Intent intent = shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application).getNextStartedActivity();
assertEquals(EODCountActivity.class, shadowOf(intent).getIntentClass());
```

This is the result I get: (As you can see, both of these `java.lang.Class` objects have same path but they are not equal)

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.Class<class com.xyz.storeapp.activities.EODCountActivity> but was: java.lang.Class<class com.xyz.storeapp.activities.EODCountActivity>
Expected :java.lang.Class<class com.xyz.storeapp.activities.EODCountActivity> 
Actual   :java.lang.Class<class com.xyz.storeapp.activities.EODCountActivity>
```

Is it possible that same java.lang.Class object have different references?

Comment: For _class equality_ they must also be loaded by the same class loader! In your case that might not be the case.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the class loaders for both the classes using `clazz.getClassLoader()` and they are indeed different. These are the results I get:


`org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader@51e8d066`
`org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@470f1802`


If you put this into an answer I will accept that

Comment: You can easily post your own answer (with much more details than I am able to give) and accept it.